# casting as date in hive giving incorrect result

Tags: hive

hi i have the following query:

```
select 
first_tran,
cast(substr(first_tran,1,6) as int) as yyyymm,
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr(first_tran,1,6) , 'yyyymm'))


from
t.table
```

wher first_tran takes format as a string: e.g. 20190804.

however i am getting the following:

[image]

i want to calculate the difference between two YYYYMM values e.g. the first_tran column and say 202308. However i am unsure how to do this when the above is not being cast right (the final column). why is the final column showing 2019-01-01 and not 201908?
is there an easier way to find months between two dates? (i want it in months)

Answer (score 1):

1. Syntax for month is incorrect.
   Pls note month in hive is `MM` in upper case. Lowercase `mm` is minutes. If you look at your output you can see it is showing 8minutes which is correct.(Screenshot below)

```
select 
first_tran,
cast(substr(first_tran,1,6) as int) as yyyymm,
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr(first_tran,1,6) , 'yyyyMM'))
```

2. In hive(version higher than 1.3) you can use `months between()` to calculate months between two given dates/timestamp.

```
select  months_between('2023-01-10', '2020-01-10'); --result will be a fraction
```

[image]